# Put Route Successful But Not Updating C#

Tags: c#

Refactoring some C# code and I am trying to create a new update method. It is working successfully but its not actually updating. This is my first time doing this in C# so I have been working off a few blogs and I can't tell whats different from what I saw on there. Here are the 2 solutions I tried:

```
public async Task<BillableDto> PutBillable(Guid Id, BillableDto billable)
{
    var view = await _context.Billables
                             .Where(b => b.Id == Id)
                             .SingleOrDefaultAsync();

    if (view == null) 
        throw new NotFoundException("BillableNotFound");
    
    view.Id = billable.Id;
    view.Name = billable.Name;
    view.Cost = billable.Cost;
    view.Type = billable.Type;
    view.PunchId = billable.PunchId;
    view.Punches = billable.Punches;

    _context.Update(view);

    return new BillableDto
        {
            Id = view.Id,
            Name = view.Name,
            Cost = view.Cost,
            Type = view.Type,
            PunchId = view.PunchId,
            Punches = view.Punches
        };
}
```

Attempt #2:

```
public async Task<bool> PutBillable(Guid Id, BillableDto billable)
{
    var view = await _context.Billables
                             .Where(b => b.Id == Id)
                             .SingleOrDefaultAsync();

    if (view == null) 
        throw new NotFoundException("BillableNotFound");
    
    view.Id = billable.Id;
    view.Name = billable.Name;
    view.Cost = billable.Cost;
    view.Type = billable.Type;
    view.PunchId = billable.PunchId;
    view.Punches = billable.Punches;

    _context.Update(view);

    return true 
}
```

Any tips on these here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not entirely clear what database and database access layer you're using - *assuming* it's some kind of Entity Framework - then you're most likely misunderstanding the `Update` method on the context.

Here's what the [official MS docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontext.update?view=efcore-7.0) says:

*Begins tracking the given entity and entries reachable from the given entity using the Modified state by default, but see below for cases when a different state will be used.*

Most importantly: it does ***NOT*** actually apply any update back to the database - for that, you'd need to call

```
await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

Also: since you're loading the `view` from the context, and then making changes to it - you don't even need to call `.Update` at all... the `view` will already be marked as "Modified" by the EF change tracker.

So try something like this:

```
public async Task<bool> PutBillable(Guid Id, BillableDto billable)
{
    var view = await _context.Billables
                             .Where(b => b.Id == Id)
                             .SingleOrDefaultAsync();

    if (view == null) 
        throw new NotFoundException("BillableNotFound");
    
    view.Id = billable.Id;
    view.Name = billable.Name;
    view.Cost = billable.Cost;
    view.Type = billable.Type;
    view.PunchId = billable.PunchId;
    view.Punches = billable.Punches;

    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should call `_context.SaveChanges()` to apply these changes on your database. According to the [Microsoft documentations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontext.update?view=efcore-7.0), calling `_context.Update(view)` just marks your object as an updated entry in DbContext change list.

```
 public async Task<bool> PutBillable(Guid Id, BillableDto billable)
 {
     var view = await _context.Billables
                              .Where(b => b.Id == Id)
                              .SingleOrDefaultAsync();
 
     if (view == null) 
         throw new NotFoundException("BillableNotFound");

     view.Id = billable.Id;
     view.Name = billable.Name;
     view.Cost = billable.Cost;
     view.Type = billable.Type;
     view.PunchId = billable.PunchId;
     view.Punches = billable.Punches;
 
     _context.Update(view);
     _context.SaveChanges();

     return true 
 }
```

Comment: The `_context.Update()` is even needed at all ....

Comment: In this case yes. but when you fetch your entity as non-tracking entry, it must be called.